# Avoid timout error in mongo/node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use the following while querying my mongoDB as party of a simple api.

```
function queryDB(db,path,request,response){
    var collection = db.collection('workingCaseDB');
    collection.findOne({name:query}, function (err,result) {
        if(err)
            sendError(db,err,request,response);
        else
            displayResults(db,result,request,response);
    });
}
```

If no result is found this stalls for a while and then throws a timeout error.  What can I do to make this fail more gracefully where there is no result in the database?  Namely, whenever a result is found the query takes <3 seconds, but where no result is found, it takes 10 seconds or so to timeout and throw the error.  How can I cut this down to 3 seconds.

Comment: No results means the db has to check the whole collection and it seems this takes 10 seconds. `findOne` will return you the first match, if the first match is found in the top 30% of the data to be checked it will take <= 3 seconds. If it's to be found in the bottom 30% of the data to be checked it will take > 6 seconds.

You might need to look at creating a sensible index for your query to speed up.

Comment: Whatever you use in your query, try to index it properly and then it will fly...